# How to run one sample multiple times independent of the number of threads in Thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i have the need to run one http request sample more times than the rest of the samples in the Test group, for example, i need to run for 10 users, but for each of them, i need to run one of the samples multiple times, lets say 10, is there a way to achieve it?

1) I set "Number of Threads (Users)" in Thread group to 10, so i have 10 total users (with data taken for every thread from a CVS file, with equal number of rows and threads, so 1 thread is an unique data set.

2) I make some requests after, but for only one of the requests, i need to make it like 100 times in parallel for the same data for every thread, so in total, i will make 1000 (100 http requests for 10 unique users/threads) requests to that endpoint

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found the loop controller, but its not making the 100 http requests at the same time for each thread in the thread group, it makes another one when the first ends

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly got your requirements, to wit:

1. You need to execute one sampler more times than other samplers
2. The execution must occur at exactly the same moment

The most obvious choice would be either [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler) or [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) (depending on the nature of your requests). You can install both test elements using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image: JMeter Parallel Sampler installation via Plugins Manager]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! so if i need to run lets say 10 of the same sample in parallel, its there a way to not having to add 10 same samples inside it? like a subthreads ammount for that particular parallel sample?

Comment: Normally if you want to execute a request by 10 threads at the same time - all you need is to add a [Synchronizing Timer](Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer) as a child of the request and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to `10`. However it will not be compatible with your test design.

Comment: I made different tests with Parallel and also with Synchronizing Timer but its not having the result i need, i need that for every Thread in the Thread group (with specific data from one CSV file), one of the requests make more than 100 parallel request of the same sample for that data set

Comment: i have updated the question because i notice the absense of the CVS unique data per thread, im sorry for that